# Getting appnode log trace throught agent REST API

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

I need to get the trace log of application execution throught the Rest Api of bw agent, any way to do this ?

Regard

Answer (score 0):

You can't, All available resources are: http://host:5555/index.html.

this is reached after setting and satrting bwagent apiserver.

Best regards

[bwagent api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMiDK.png)